Wordpress admin control panel redirects to a homepage
When i logging in my admin panel, site redirects to a home page...
I don't have any ideas, how to solve this problem, need help(
Checked admin data in DB, its Ok. Tried to use repair function in phpMyAdmin, still no reaction. I haven't any backups, but i think the point in the BD: I used WP All Import for migration Users tables, and when it was running, suddenly i was kicked out from admin panel and admin pass was cleared.
Also i tried to delete all data in Users tables and then add one admin, still not works.

I don't know what is causing the issue, but you can start debugging the problem by deactivating all the plugins to see if one of them is causing conflicts.
If you can't do it via admin panel, try to install the WP-CLI tool and do it from the terminal.
There are many tutorials on the internet of how to install the wp-cli tool, maybe this one could help.
Go to your terminal and navigate to the wordpress folder and run this command to deactivate all the plugins:
cd <your_wordpress_installation_folder>
wp plugin deactivate --all

If the problem disappears try activating the plugins again one by one to see which one is causing the issue.
Or, if the problem is still there, maybe the issue is caused by the theme, so you can also try to activate one of the default WordPress themes:
wp theme install twentytwentyfour --activate

Please try not to touch the database if you are not sure what you are doing, as you could break the WordPress installation. Additionally, the problem might not be in the database, it could be a script in the active WordPress theme or active plugins.

I disabled all plugins, but after login it still redirecting. Tried to deactivate theme too, but didn't helped..

Try upgrading or downgrading your WordPress version, just in case some Wordpress core file have been modified. You can use WP-CLI tool to do this safely. E.g: wp core update --version=5.5.3 --force and then try again with all plugins and themes disabled

I think the user present in DB does not have correct permissions and due to that it is causing the problem.
What you can do is add another admin user from PHPmyadmin by following the directions at https://wpengine.com/support/add-admin-user-phpmyadmin/.
Then you can try to log in using a new user, if it works then my guess was right.
Thank you! :)

Thanks for answer, but still don't works. It is logging in, but redirecting to a homepage of site

Do you have any redirection plugin add to the website, if yes, try to disable it by remaining it from file manager.
